# How is a .zip compressed archive structured?

Tags: compression, zip, archive

I'm looking into how popular compression algorithms work so I could possibly implement my own zip archiver.  Are there any resources about how exactly zip works? How is a .zip compressed archive structured?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. [ZIP format documentation](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)
2. [DEFLATE algorithm](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt)
3. [ZLib compressed data format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt)